# What is the massive CD drive used in the movie "Licence to Kill"?

Tags: storage, cd-rom

In the movie *[Licence to Kill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licence_to_Kill)*, James Bond breaks into Felix Leiter's house and gets a CD out from behind a picture. He then sticks a CD in an absolutely massive CD drive. It was about three times the width of the CD. This movie was released in 1989. I've never seen anything like that before. Did such CD drives actually exist?

Sorry, I don't have a picture.

Comment: How did he put it in? Slot? Music box-style hinged cover?

Comment: Perhaps a Videodisc?

Comment: What are you talking about? The standard width for hifi equipment is about 42 cm, i.e. 3.5 times the width of a CD.

Comment: BTW, you might want to think about where the term "CD" comes from. I suppose it's just a matter of time until we see someone asking about "A mobile phone, except it's stationary", or "UAV with a pilot".

Comment: @Acccumulation that time is already here   "why do old people say that a phone is ringing?"  or "why do old people hold a thumb to their ear and a pinky finger to their mouth to pantomime a phone call?"

Comment: @Acccumulation: I've heard there are a magic kind of electric guitar that you don't have to plug in. Not only that but they don't even need batteries!

Comment: @Criggie - for me, the ultimate expression is the symbol above the "1" button on the software keyboard of a smartphone: it signifies digital voicemail by depicting a reel-to-reel tape recorder (not even a cassette!), something I doubt anyone born since the advent of the mobile phone boom would ever have seen in real life, let alone have used.

Comment: @Spratty You underestimate how many of us watch Techmoan on YouTube!

Comment: @Dai - you youngsters and your newfangled nostalgia!

Comment: How, about, simply, use of the word "dialing" to execute a phone connection.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: As a millenial who has never actually dialed a rotary phone, I think of "dial" the same way I think of any other verb: It's just an opaque word meaning "to input numbers into the telephone system." I don't associate it with a physical dial that you can turn.

Comment: @Kevin I think that was the whole point of this comments discussion, you have just confirmed that the origins of those terms are lost in the techno-past.

Comment: @Spratty did you ever see the inside of a cassette? (I know, I know, but it is still literally reel-to-reel :))

Comment: I believe there were laserdisc players that could ALSO play CDs. I seem to remember some had a groove within the larger groove. So this scene would be totally plausible.

Comment: As was already mentioned in the existing answer, 12cm-diameter LDs existed; as can be seen in [its service manual](https://www.domesday86.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Philips-VP415-Service-Manual-hires.pdf), the VP415 has the requisite groove. This is used independently of the ability to play back audio CDs; the VP415 can’t do that.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As far as I remember, this wasn't a CD, but (supposed to be) a [Laserdisc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaserDisc), and he was using a Philips player (the movie contained several Philips machines). Laserdiscs were available in different sizes between 12 cm, which is like a CD and up to 30 cm ([LP size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LP_record)).

In a technical way, the movie screwed up, as Laserdisks were neither digital (they used an analogue format) nor writable. Except for the [LV-ROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LV-ROM) which could carry digital data as well - still not writable.

Looking at this picture from [Starringthecomputer](http://starringthecomputer.com/snapshots/license_to_kill_philips_p3230_2.jpg),

[image]

it seems plausible that it is a [Philips VP-415](https://www.domesday86.com/?page_id=316):

[image]

(The same drive was used for the [Acorn/BBC Domesday Project](https://www.domesday86.com/?page_id=2140).)

Comment: I've only ever seen 12" laserdisks.  Never seen a small one before.

Comment: Categorizing "not writeable" as "screwed up" is quite disputable, especially seen from copyright, IPR and commercial viewpoints. The music industry has probably considered the CD/RW as a "screwed-up" thing exactly for the opposite reason.

Comment: @tofro I haven't seen the film, but couldn't "in technical way they screwed up" be about the role of that disk in the plot of the film?

Comment: @tofro Erm (re-) watch the film. Story goes that Felix had stored (written) sensible data onto the disk, prior to his death, and Bond retrieves it later on, using the Philips setup. There is no dispute about copyright or alike involved. It has simply screwed up by using the wrong props - maybe in part because the CD-R was only finished a few month after filming had started.

Comment: Re *"the movie contained several Philips machines"*: [Product placement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_placement)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Bond movies has even been called the king of product placement.... https://blog.hollywoodbranded.com/blog/james-bond-product-placement-the-definitive-timeline-of-brands-in-bond

Comment: Might be worth mentioning there were writable Magneto-Optical discs that size in existence when this was filmed.  The LV ROM player depicted is not that, and MO discs are generally contained inside a caddy, not a bare disc.  But the concept of a big writable disc itself isn't far-fetched, they just got the details wrong.

Comment: @mnem The disk used was smaller. More like a CD. And most definitely not a MO.

Comment: @Raffzahn Ah. You meant the movie guys with "they" - That's not very clear from your post. I assumed you meant Philips.

Comment: @tofro I wouldn't consider the question being about Philips policies but prop use in a move. The world is bigger than just computes isn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn Yes, but only slightly.

Comment: @tofro :)  In some way you hit it right home. They have creeped into way too many areas.

Comment: I had the same interpretation as @tofro: I thought you were saying the designers of Laserdisc screwed up the design by making those choices.  I edited with clearer phrasing to convey what you meant, @ Raffzahn.

Comment: Perhaps the spy gadget team had developed a writeable LaserDisc, using heat / light sensitive chemicals like CD-R.  And that's what Felix Leiter used.  Given the gadgets Q develops for Bond, that's a very plausible explanation.

Comment: @AndrewMorton medial capitals are a game for trademark lawyers and marketing  'experts'. I do not consider them suitable for writing.

Comment: The first picture even shows another Philips product. The PC on top of the LV-ROM is a [Philips NMS9100](https://www.homecomputermuseum.nl/collectie/philips/philips-nms9100/).

Comment: @cup: To places (USA) I've seen karaoke in the 1980s and 1990s used smaller disks that would hold about four songs with video, which I think was the dominant format before CD+G was invented.

Comment: [_There were_ writeable (and even rewriteable) LaserDiscs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaserDisc#Recordable_formats), although they were very rare and not marketed to the general public.

Answer (score 17):

That is a Philips VP415 LV-ROM player.